# new to views, create custom box and duplicating it

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm new to IOS...
I want to set up a view that has multiple objects. These objects can vary in number according to a result from a rest webservice I host on a website. I have accomplished retrieving the results and processing the json. However I'm now not sure how to present the information. I would like to have a box that would appear for each of my results that contain an image a title and a button. Also I would like to have this in two columns.
First I thought of doing this manually, drawing 8 boxes, and populate manually the titles and actions with the results. However I'm sure there must be a way that I can create one box and then duplicate it for each of my results.
Also, I'm clueless on how to download the image. I got the full url of it but I don't know how to download it and display it.

Can someone point me into the right direction.

Thanks,

B

Answer (score 0):

To download images, I recommend NSURLConnection. As for displaying your data, a UITableView is the standard approach. You can customize the row appearance as much or as little as the project requires.

Comment: Thanks for the NSURLConnection to get the images! However on UITable I can only get one column. How can I make it 2 columns, considering this is for Ipad and it would be too little information for 1 column.

Comment: UITableView only has 1 column. You can display more data by placing labels in the UITableViewCell such that it gives the appearance of multiple columns.